# Crop z-axis of PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots

I try to implement the following image of the function `1/(x*y)` I plotted using WolframAlpha using the PGFPlots package:

[image: This is how it should look like]

The function is not defined if `x=0` or `y=0`, so I split it up into four parts like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[zmin=-20,zmax=20]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:-0.1,y domain=0.1:1]{1/(x*y)};
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0.1:1,y domain=-1:-0.1]{1/(x*y)};
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-1:-0.1,y domain=-1:-0.1]{1/(x*y)};
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0.1:1,y domain=0.1:1]{1/(x*y)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is how the result looks like:

[image: my try]

Without the `[zmin=-20,zmax=20]` after `\begin{axis}` one cannot see that the values grow very large close to the x-axis and y-axis as easily as in the image from WolframAlpha. This is because the first image crops the values of the function at `-20` and `20`. Adding `[zmin=-20,zmax=20]` after `\begin{axis}` however still draws bigger values of the function if their projection is in the bounding box, which looks really strange.

How can I avoid this and reproduce the image of WolframAlpha?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd say that Wolfram Alpha uses a different viewing angle. Have you tried modifying it?

Comment: Related (in german only, but images should help anyway): http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/7387/wie-erhalte-ich-einen-glatten-rand-bei-beschrankten-plots

Comment: @PhilippImhof: Thanks for your reply. I added `view={25}{65}` to the parameters of the axis and now the viewing angle is almost the same as in the other picture. It still plots values bigger than 20 and looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/uogwt5y.png

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger: Thanks for this helpful link. Adding `restrict z to domain*=-20:20` instead of `zmin` and `zmax` changed exactly the points I wanted to change. It now looks like this, which is fine: http://i.imgur.com/xtmZKpI.png There are still these plain areas close to `(0,0)`, do you know a way to avoid them since they are not actually part of the plot?

Comment: I think currently this is not possible. When using `restrict z to domain*` all values that are outside of the specified domain are set to the limit of the domain. That is why you get this result. To "clip" these values you can use the non-stared variant `restrict z to domain` but that would lead to another problem ...